# Textview Countdown Label

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to put a countdown on my textview. my .h and .m files are setup like below. Basically, all I am looking for is a textview a label that counts down from 140 as the user enters text. Once the textview reaches 140 characters, the user should no longer be able to enter text. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be great! Thanks!

**in my .h file:**

```
@interface LeaveTipViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *tipCancelButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *tipSubmitButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tipText;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *countLabel;

- (IBAction)tipCancelPressed:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)tipSubmitPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

**in my .m file:**

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    int len = tipText.text.length;
    countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",140-len];

}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    BOOL flag = NO;
    if([text length] == 0)
    {
        if([tipText.text length] != 0)
        {
            flag = YES;
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else if([[tipText text] length] > 139)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your viewController interface LeaveTipViewController : UIViewController

set self.tipText.delegate = self

And use this two methods

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range   replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
 NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
 return (newLength > 140) ? NO : YES;
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
 int maxChars = 140;
 int charsLeft = maxChars - [textView.text length];

        if(charsLeft == 0) {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No more characters"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have reached the character limit of %d.",maxChars]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

  self.lblLettersCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d characters left",charsLeft];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having trouble doing the self.tipText.delegate = self... Where do I put that part?

Comment: In viewDidLoad method. Or in Interface Builder just point the delegate field to your class

Comment: woohoo! ok it works but I am getting an error: assign to id<UItextViewDelegate> from incompatible type leavetipcontroller const_strong

Answer (score 4):

Just change your this method to

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    return textView.text.length + (text.length - range.length) <= 140;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate the actual text that would exist after the edit is completed before you decide whether to allow the edit or not:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *resultingText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    return ([resultingText length] <= 140);
}
```

Comment: thanks much. i can't even seem to get the textViewDidChange to fire properly. am I doing something incorrectly in my .h file? have any idea why this wold not be working?

Comment: Have you set your controller as the text view delegate?

Comment: Probably not - ill look around and see how to do that

Comment: In your interface define that you implement the protocol and then drag a connection from the text view to the controller in the XIB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to check and get the number of characters:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSInteger maxLength = 140;

    NSString *text = textView.text;

    if([[textView text] length] > maxLength )
    {
        textView.text = [text substringToIndex:[text length]-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks much. i can't even seem to get the textViewDidChange to fire properly. am I doing something incorrectly in my .h file? have any idea why this wold not be working?